# Forcing Python to free memory

Tags: python, garbage-collection

The behavior of the system memory as displayed by htop is very non intuitive when filling it up and freeing with python. Can someone explain the basics of what is happening?

In short, I wrote a function memfill() to quickly use up memory by appending huge ranges of float64 into a list 'l'.

Afterwards, deleting the variable l and/or invoking gc.collect() does not always return the memory to the initial state. Sometimes it takes a while, and sometimes weirdly enough it just does it after calling l and returning a 'variable not found' error.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the expected behavior should be, that if l is not being referenced by anything, deleting this variable should free all the memory it was using right? And if not, at least it should after calling gc.collect() ? True or false?

Comment: Sounds true enough to me, but bear in mind that some other application may have allocated some memory, so you see less of a drop than you expect.

Comment: I'd be surprised if python guarantees that it will return memory to the system.  I'd expect for a lot of things it uses malloc and free that make no such guarantee

Comment: Yeah, and the OS might not actually reclaim the memory even if the Python process has freed it, waiting until it has to